# Install and run Google apps script from domain administartor account

Tags: google-apps-script

is it possible to  install and run my Google apps script to all users within the domain as a domain admin?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. AFAIK anyway.

What you can do is, on most Google APIs, using Apps Script `UrlFetch` instead of the built-in services, you can [impersonate](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) the users if you're running from the domain admin account.